# How to display dynamic text and images with sanity?

Tags: reactjs, web, text, e-commerce, sanity

```
 index.js                                         export const        
 getServerSideProps = async () => {
 const query = '*[_type == "product"]';
 const products = await client.fetch(query);

 const bannerQuery = '*[_type == "banner"]';
 const bannerData = await client.fetch(bannerQuery);

 return {
 props: {products, bannerData}
 }import { urlFor } from '../lib/client';

 HeroBanner.JSX
 const HeroBanner  = ({heroBanner}) => {
  return (
 <div className='hero-banner-container'>
  <div>
    <p className='beats-solo'> {heroBanner.smallText} </p>
    <h3> {heroBanner.midText} </h3>
    <h1> {heroBanner.largeText1} </h1>
    {console.log(heroBanner.largeText1)}
    <img src={urlFor(heroBanner.image)} alt='Trending'      
className='hero-banner-image' />

Client.js
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityClient({
projectId:'*********',
dataset:'production',
apiVersion:'2022-12-04',
useCdn:true,
token:process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_TOKEN
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

This is the code here I tried. If normal text is in the p,h1, and h3         elements it works fine. However, the code I have there now is
{heroBanner.smallText} and that's where my problem starts. The text   doesn't display when I use those values. I did change the values on sanity.io through localhost to what I want and nothing displays. P.S: When I console logged the bannerData I got the values I'm now trying to display.

Answer (score 0):

sanity body text doesn't get displayed, you need to convert it using block-content

npm install @sanity/block-content-to-react --save
import SanityBlockContent from "@sanity/block-content-to-react";

then wrap the text you want to display in block-content.
As an example, post.body is what I want to display, it'll go something like this SanityBlockContent blocks={post.body} projectId="******" dataset="*******" />